# Finding documents using date arithmetic with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose document which has these properties:

```
DocSchema = new Schema({
    issue_date: Date,
    days_to_expire: Number
});

DocSchema.virtual.get(function () {
   return moment(this.issue_date).add(this.days_to_expire, 'days');
});
```

I want to find all document that are to expire within a week, is this possible with this schema definition?

The operation I'm looking for is something like this:

```
today - (issue_date + days_to_expire) <= 7
```

How can I query something like that using mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be saving yourself a lot of trouble if you just store the expiration date inside the document as well. Then you're looking at a simple `find({ expiration_date: { $gte: today, $lte: todayPlusSeven } })`. Otherwise you're left calculating the expiration date in an aggregation and matching based off that.